# removing duplicate based two coulmn value.

Tags: mysql, database, excel, openoffice-calc, ods

I need a help from you guys.

my data is like this

```
A A value 1 value 2
A B value# value#
B A value# value#
D F value# value#
V F value# value#
```

i need either of one row either A B or B A.it should look like this

```
A A value 1 value 2
A B value# value#
B A value# value#  .....this record should be removed
D F value# value#
V F value# value#
```

please help on this isssue.

Thanks all of you

sanjay

Comment: please help on this issue..

Comment: what is reason being voted down.....

Answer (score 0):

with your sample case, you can do something like

```
delete from table1 t1
where exists (select null
from table1
where t1.col1 = col2 and t1.col2 = col1 and t1.col1 > col1
)
```

But that won't remove duplicates if you have

```
A B
A B => won't be removed
A A
```

If you have a surrogate key (like an autoincremented id) in your table, you could do this, which would also remove one of the duplicated `A B`

```
delete from table1 t1
    where exists (select null
    from table1
    where ((t1.col1 = col2 and t1.col2 = col1) or (t1.col1 = col1 and t1.col2 = col2) and t1.id > id
    )
```